# PHP stop 2 functions that calls each other

Tags: php, recursion

Let's say I have 2 functions that can call each other

```
 public static function goToAction($action,$sender_id)
{
    $actions = array();
    $logic = file_get_contents('../../logic/logic.json');
    $logic_array = json_decode($logic, true);
    unset($logic);
    if (!isset($logic_array[$action])) {
        return false;
    } else {
        foreach ($logic_array[$action] as $action) {
            $actions[] = self::parseActionType($action,$sender_id);
        }
    }
    return $actions;
}


 public static function parseActionType($actions,$sender_id)
{
    $data = array();
    foreach ($actions as $key => $action) {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'goto': { 
                      $goto_actions = self::goToAction($action,$sender_id);
                      foreach ($goto_actions as $goto_action){
                      $data[] = $goto_action;
                  } break;
                  ...
   }
}
return $data;
}
```

and here is my json file:

```
 "no_return": [
{ "text": "Должно быть: 1, 2, 3"},
{ "text": "1" },
{ "goto": "2nr", "no_return": true},
{ "text": "5" }
],
"2nr": [
{ "text": "2" },
{ "goto": "3", "no_return": true},
{ "text": "4"}
],
"3nr": [
{ "text": "3" }
],
```

it returns 12345 , and its right, but how can I make it return 123 if `no_return` is setted to `true`? Maybe function must return something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($logic_array[$action] as $action) {
    $actions[] = self::parseActionType($action,$sender_id);
    if (!empty($action['no_return'])) { break; }
}
```

Using break inside of a loop stops it even if there are more element left, there is also continue this will end the current run and proceed with the next element.

Comment: `isset($new_action['no_return']) && $new_action['no_return'] == true` can be reduced to `!empty($new_action['no_return'])`

Comment: Thanks you are right, I first wanted to do a type safe check.

Comment: It doesnt help, i dont need to break all next iterations, i need to prevent what goes after "no_return" in this case its `{"text":"5"}` which calls in first iteration, when recursion ends

Comment: Now I unterstand your code a bit better, I adjusted mine.